# Derby server not starting

Tags: database, derby

I have installed derby 10.13.1.1

I have set DERBY_HOME to location where the s/w is installed anf Path variable till the bin location of derby . I have also edited the startNetworkServer.bat and changed @echo off to @echo on but still when i start derby server using cmd prompt i get this error :

**DERBY_HOME is set incorrectly or derby.jar could not be located.
Please set the DERBY_HOME environment variable to the path where you installed Derby.**

I have set the derby home correctly and checked out everything , still cant find the solution .

Comment: Cut-and-paste the **actual** output into the question. Also, try running `java -jar $DERBY_HOME/lib/derbyrun.jar server start` (or, if you are on Windows, `java -jar %DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbyrun.jar server start`) and copy-and-paste the output from that terminal window and that command into the question.

Comment: Thanks :) Got the solution anyway. I didn't place derby in the same folder as java , so was facing issues